# Undefined Index Error & No Output From POST/GET

Tags: php

I'm setting up a simple form on my local server, but the POST and GET methods both return nothing.

I discovered this problem when making my own form. Then I tried using online tutorial codes to see if they have the same problem, they do. I'm almost sure that it is not the codes problem because of this. When I 'fix' these codes by using isset() or ??'' the resulting page is blank.

Im using Windows 10 x86, PHP 7, node.js local server, code copied from https://www.w3schools.com/php7/php7_forms.asp and https://www.w3resource.com/php/super-variables/$_REQUEST.php .

Does anybody know if there's anything wrong with PHP or is it something else?

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

webserver.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var execPHP = require('./execphp.js')();

execPHP.phpFolder = 'C:\\Users\\Dshop\\Desktop\\php-7.3.3\\Server1';

app.use('*.php',function(request,response,next) {
    execPHP.parseFile(request.originalUrl,function(phpResult) {
        response.write(phpResult);
        response.end();
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Node server listening on port 3000!');
});
```

execphp.js

```
/**
*
*/
class ExecPHP {
    /**
    *
    */
    constructor() {
        this.phpPath = 'C:\\Users\\Dshop\\Desktop\\php-7.3.3\\php.exe';
        this.phpFolder = '';
    }   
    /**
    *
    */
    parseFile(fileName,callback) {
        var realFileName = this.phpFolder + fileName;

        console.log('parsing file: ' + realFileName);

        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        var cmd = this.phpPath + ' ' + realFileName;

        exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            callback(stdout);
        });
    }
}
module.exports = function() {
    return new ExecPHP();
};
```

[what shows up in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NUXM.png)

[what results in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6K2I.png)

Comment: `isset()` is not a fix it or something similiar is a pre-requisite

Comment: Remember there are a number of ways to launch a web page. ONLY when you launch it from the SUBMIT of a form will the `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays actually get filled

Comment: However I do not see a reason why these 2 scripts would not work, if you submit the form to the second script

Comment: @alex are you sure that PHP is actually configured properly? What happens if you do <?php echo "hello world"; ?> do you get the expected string? I cant see anything fundamentally wrong with your code.

Comment: Is there anything in the php error logs?

Comment: You sure that the code is of `welcome.php` and not some other file? Take a look at your welcome.php again..

Comment: @Andy it gives me hello world ?>

Comment: hmm, with the ?> at the end? looks like php is working. or maybe something else is happening. what about <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> you should get a page with the PHP config.

Comment: @Andy yes i got it

Comment: "PHP 7, node.js local server" — How are you mixing Node.js and PHP?

Comment: @Quentin I'm using node.js to run the local server that can display results of php files, ill add the webserver code that i got from the internet aswell.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I did run it from the submit first. I started with index.php which includes the form, then it went to welcome.php after, showing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using to run the PHP is very basic. The key thing missing that is relevant to your interests is that you do nothing to populate `$_POST`. You're simply executing the PHP program with no input.

To run PHP from inside a Node.js program, you should probably use a module like [node-php](https://github.com/davidcoallier/node-php).

You might be better off using something like Apache HTTPD to run the PHP (with mod_php) and forward requests to a separate Node.js server for code running there (using mod_proxy).

Comment: i was just about to say this in a comment.

Comment: Ill try this. Also, could I get some explanation on how $_POST is not populated? Since I did add some input in before I submitted the form. Im new, explain please.

Comment: "could I get some explanation on how $_POST is not populated" — You don't put data in a place where PHP will take it and put it in `$_POST` therefore `$_POST` has no data in it.

Comment: @Quentin Shouldn't the text boxes be a place to put data in? I think I did that. (two imgur links)

Comment: The data is in the HTTP request you send to Node.js. The Node.js code then ignores it and runs the PHP without doing anything to send the data to the PHP.